# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, packaging

I imported some existing Eclipse based Android projects into Android Studio. Along, the way I fixed several issues and I am hitting this one last issue (hopefully):

```
Execution failed for task ':myapp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/mypackage/myapp/BuildConfig.class
```

**Here are dependencies:**
**module1:**

```
dependencies {
    provided files('src/main/libs/opencv.jar')
}
```

**module2:**

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/autobanh.jar')
    compile files('libs/libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar')
}
```

**module3:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('src/main/libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

**module4:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module3')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

**Finally the App:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module1')
    compile project(':module2')
    compile project(':module3')
    compile project(':module4')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

How do I fix this? I tried the following so far:

[transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug,com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783163/transformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-com-android-build-api-transform-transform)

[Execution failed for transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. (Volley)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199930/execution-failed-for-transformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-volley)

with no help. Any thoughts?

Comment: Each module has to have a different package name in their manifest. All modules except the last one must be libraries.

Comment: @EugenPechanec You were spot on with the duplicate package name. I had a duplicate package name and had set:


    enforceUniquePackageName = false

After changing the module4's package name it is past that issue. Thanks a ton. Please record your comment as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

> duplicate entry: com/mypackage/myapp/BuildConfig.class

`BuildConfig` is a class generated for each module (Android library or application) according to package name specified in its manifest.

Make sure all your modules have a unique package name in their `AndroidManifest.xml`